# django with react using web pack

Tags: django, reactjs

I have added react js in django using webpack loader

```
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'bundles4/',
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json'),
    }
}
```

First time all things are OK. 
But when I change any code in react then don't change application with new code.
Is it cache problem?

Comment: Could you provide more information? This is just a small part of the implementation that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a cache issue. You need to compile your bundle with your current settings in order to get the new bundles reflecting the changes.

You can run this on your command line to compile your new bundle:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

This should create a bundle at `assets/bundles/main-{XXXX}.js` where {XXXX} is a hash.

But you don’t want to create bundles manually every time you make changes to your code.

You can run on your command line:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch
```

This will leave the compiler running and compile bundles automatically when you change any of your source files. You’ll need to restart it if you make any changes to the webpack configuration though.

To go further, you can look at webpack-dev-server and react-hot-loader for hot reloading your components:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server react-hot-loader
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer create-react-app, they do everything for you, you don't have to worry about the webpack configurations. I've created a sample github gist to show you how simple it is to integrate django with create-react-app.

https://gist.github.com/ibrahimawadhamid/dd4091196b0c7b25cca33d72b044efaf